# Worksheet keeps Protecting on all cells

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code setup but I need it to stop protecting the other cells that does not need to be protected. I cannot unlock the cels via Format cells - Protection because I need certains cells lock when `B7:B1000` contains text "PA" "PU". If it is blank or has any other text it should not protect those cells.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
Application.EnableEvents = False 'prevent infinite event loops

Me.Unprotect ' else won't be able to modify locked cells

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B7:B1000")) Is Nothing Then
    'User edited a cell in this range.
    With Range("F1:M1").Offset(Target.Row - 1, 0)
        If (Target.Value = "PA" Or Target.Value = "PU") Then
            .Interior.Color = RGB(77, 77, 77) 'gray
            .Locked = True
        Else
            .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255) 'white
            .Locked = False
        End If

    End With
End If

ExitProcedure:
    Me.Protect
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume ExitProcedure

Set wkB = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with the code. It is protecting the other cells because the locked property of those cells is already `True`. Note that Excel by default sets the property to `True` in a new worksheet. So before you run the above code, manually set your range's property to `False`

Comment: I dont think I explained this properyly. All cells in    F1:m1000 cannot have the locked property. The above code is to only protect if target Value is PA or PU but everytime i click on a row that does not contain PA or PU it still protects cells     F1:M1000. I want it to unprotect itself if I click anywhere on the sheet where it does not contain PA or PU

Comment: `but everytime i clicke on a row that does not contain PA or PU it still protects cells F1:M1000.` Worksheet_Change event doesn't fire when you select a row. Your cells are already protected even before the code is run. Try this. Whichever row is protected, type "PA" or "PU" there. What happens?

Comment: It tells me to its protected and therefore read only. Problem here is I will not be the only person using this sheet, there will be 70 others and I do not want everyone to keep unprotecting the sheet.

Comment: Before you share the worksheet with other users, manually set the locked property of all the cells in that range to false and then re-protect it. After that you will not get the error.

Comment: How do I do that? I am a complete beginner on VBA

Comment: One moment, posting a detailed answer.

Comment: Thats not exactly what I wanted but its done the trick. I will leave at that. Thank you

Comment: I am almost done answering. So you want me to discard my answer?

Comment: How do i mark this as answered?

Comment: no if you have more detailed answer please let me know. It may help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I mentioned above in the comment, the problem is not with the code. What you are experiencing is a default behavior of excel. By default all excel cell's `.Locked` property is `Checked`. What you need to do is prepare your worksheet first before distributing your workbook.

**Preparing Your Worksheet**

1. Comment all the `Worksheet_Change` code . This is important else your `Worksheet_Change` code will fire automatically when we will make the below changes.
2. Unprotect your worksheet manually.
3. Next delete all values from `B7:B1000`.
4. Select `F7:M1000` and right click on it and set it's locked property to `False`. This is required else Excel will `lock` the cells immaterial of the fact whether there is a value in Column B or not as the default `.Locked` proterty is `True`
5. UnComment all the `Worksheet_Change` code
6. Finally re-protect your worksheet and you are done.

**Followup from comments**

Comment the code means putting a `'` before every line of the code else the code will fire when you manually delete values from Col B.

You can also mass comment the code by selecting the complete code and clicking the "Comment Block" icon from the edit toolbar. To activate the Edit toolbar, Select the "View | Toolbars -- Edit " menu in VBA Editor as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by Comment all the Worksheet_Change code . This is important else your Worksheet_Change code will fire automatically when we will make the below changes. Do i need to change this? I get the other points

Comment: One moment. updating the post. :)